# Redirecting a POST to a php script

Tags: redirect, htaccess, proxy

This is an expansion on the second answer to the question asked [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130169/setting-up-an-api-listening-page?lq=1).

I have been trying to redirect a post request from my_website/test to wp-content/themes/my_theme/test.php but I am getting a 404 whenever I try to send it.

I have a .htaccess file in /wordpress with the contents

```
#BEGIN WordPress

Redirect 301 /test_redirect wp-content/themes/my_theme/test.php

#END WordPress
```

Is the htaccess file being used by wordpress or apache? Do I need any special configurations on either to allow them?

I saw somewhere that to allow .htaccess files you just need to change apache2.conf from AllowOveride none to all for  and Directory /var/www/>, is this the only setting I need to change?

I also saw that having proxypass enabled might interfere with the redirect, is this true? Is there a way to get around that if it is?

Edit:

Thanks to Jorin for the help with solving this problem.

I changed the location of the .htaccess file down to www instead of www/wordpress and changed the address of the php file I wanted to redirect to to the full link i.e.

```
http://www.my_website.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my_theme/test.php
```

And that redirect worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the redirect. Can you try:

```
Redirect 301 /test_redirect http://www.yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/my_theme/test.php
```

Comment: That doesn't look like it changed anything. Do you know if there is a log file that might show any errors associated with the htaccess file?

Comment: I don't think there is a log file for htaccess. If you go in your browser to /test_redirect where does it lead you to?

Comment: That's where I've been checking so far, it just leads to a 404 page.

Comment: But what is the url of the 404 page?

Comment: Still just my_website/test_redirect

Comment: Is the redirect rule on top of the htaccess file? And is the htaccess file in the public_html or www folder of your server (the root of your site)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36881/discussion-between-phenom588-and-jorin-van-vilsteren).